# Rest API to delete an attachment in Lead/Contacts?

Tags: rest-api

What is the Rest API to delete an attachment in Lead/Contacts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find the Id of the Attachment that you want to delete, and then call e.g.

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/[ID] -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -X DELETE
```

See documentation on REST calls for deleting a record: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_delete_record.htm